# Reading serial port with pymodbus3

Tags: python-3.x, modbus

I'm working on a serial port using pymodbus3.

When I run the following code the output is 'None'. Whereas I can get response from the device when test for the serial port with modpoll.

How can I fix this issue?

```
from pymodbus3.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as mbc

def PortTest(self):
    client = mbc(method="rtu", port="/dev/ttyUSB0", stopbits=1, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=9600)
    try:
        client.connect()
        coil = client.read_coils(0, 1)
        print(coil)
        client.close()
    except OSError as err:
        raise EnvironmentError(err)
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

pymodbus3 has a bug. Uninstall it and replace it with the python 3 branch of pymodbus 1.2.0. Go to github and download it.

https://github.com/bashwork/pymodbus/tree/python3

Comment: I gave up using. I did not answer because I did not try the new version

Comment: I'm not sure what to do about it, but pymodbus3 is riddled with bugs. I wasted 3 days of my time trying to figure them out only to realize that pymodbus 1.2.0 has py3 compat.

It's bad because pymodbus3 seems to have plenty of recent activity, too. I can't just outright say it's a dead module. But it sure doesn't work as well as the source it forked from.